# Disable Conditional Formatting for specific column

Tags: devexpress, conditional-formatting, xtragrid

Starting from [WinForms Data Grid v14.2](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/donw/archive/2014/11/12/winforms-data-grid-excel-inspired-conditional-formatting-coming-soon-in-v14-2.aspx) by enabling the [GridOptionsMenu.ShowConditionalFormattingItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsMenu_ShowConditionalFormattingItemtopic) property, the [Conditional Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114603) feature becomes available.

By doing a right click on any column header, the *Conditional Formatting* menu item is showed up, allowing end-users to apply conditional formatting to grid columns.

[image]

My question is that is it possible to disable the feature for a specific column? I'm thinking of having the menu item grayed out, or simply not having it (by hiding it somehow) in the list of items.

I'm aware of the fact that the cells of a specific column can be formatted by the conditional formattings put on other columns by applying the formatting to the entire row. But, my goal is only to make sure the user can not access the functionality for a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the corresponding menu-item using the [GridView.PopupMenuShowing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_PopupMenuShowingtopic) event:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Localization;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Menu;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            gridView1.PopupMenuShowing += gridView1_PopupMenuShowing;
        }
        void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e) {
            var columnMenu = e.Menu as GridViewColumnMenu;
            if(columnMenu != null && columnMenu.Column == this.gridColumn1) {
                var conditionalFormattingItem = e.Menu.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => object.Equals(x.Tag, GridStringId.MenuColumnConditionalFormatting));
                if(conditionalFormattingItem != null)
                    conditionalFormattingItem.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```